# Sharing objects between different platforms

Tags: android, .net, ios, xml, json

I wrote the server and all the Windows clients in VB.NET, and I'm using XML serialization to share objects between them.

We need to have Android and iOS devices connect to the server, but I'm not able to get XML serialization to work the way it does in .NET, so I looked at other protocols that all three implement. I was able to get Android to convert an object to JSON to send via socket stream, so if I can get iOS to do the same thing, I'll probably end up going that route and re-implement JSON instead of XML. Microsoft just makes it so easy to serialize/deserialize objects to XML.

Are there any better ways besides XML or JSON  to transmit objects between different platforms when using a socket?

Comment: (biased advice) Go JSON! No, seriously, JSON parsing/{de,}serializing libraries exist for all platforms you mention: what difficulties have you encountered which have prevented you from doing full JSON conversion?

Comment: I haven't had enough time to mess with it yet, but it wasn't putting the object type in the JSON text, so the receiving end didn't know what type it was. I'm sure I'll figure it out.

Comment: Above comment makes me laugh now that I've figured out how JSON works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement JSON in iOS, you can have a look at this tutorial :

[Ray Wenderlich's *Working with JSON in iOS 5 Tutorial*](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5).

From the first line of the tutorial :

> iOS 5 has some new built-in APIs to make it really easy to read and write JSON.

So if you're targeting iOS 5+ devices (probably the most reasonable choice today), you're good to go with JSON (I used it in a project, really easy to get working quick).